# get no syntax errors in atom nuclide and flow

Tags: android, react-native, atom-editor, flowtype, nuclide-editor

I'm using ReactNative in Atom Editor with Nuclide Extension (to build an Android App).

It's my first time with ReactNative. I followed this tutorial and included flow: 
[reactnative and flow](https://medium.com/react-native-training/getting-started-with-react-native-and-flow-d40f55746809)

i write senseless pieces of Code and Atom doesn't show any error message or hint. I'm running

```
npm run flow
```

and the flow-output says: No Errors!

When I'm running the app on Android Emulator it's the first time the errors appear. But i want to see it in the Editor and with flow.

Can someone help me getting flow to work? And how can I get Syntax Errors directly in Atom?

Comment: Add `@flow ` in a comment at top of the file, restart flow.

Comment: have this already :(

Comment: maybe it's a problem with nuclide diagnostics which is not fully supported on windows.

Comment: `npm run flow` doesn't involve Nuclide, and `No Errors!` shows that Flow is in fact running. I'm sure it's an issue with the project's configuration somehow but without more information I can't pinpoint it.